# Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$simple_replace

Tags: php, joomla, properties

Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$mind_the_id... Code is inside form, php code on this line is:

```
<?php if (!$this->seolink->mind_the_id) echo ' checked="checked"'; ?>
```

After some lines again the same Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$simple_replace

```
<input id="simple_replace0" type="radio" value="0" name="simple_replace"<?php if (!$this->seolink->simple_replace) echo ' checked="checked"'; ?> />

<input id="simple_replace1" type="radio" value="1" name="simple_replace"<?php if ($this->seolink->simple_replace) echo ' checked="checked"'; ?> />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simply means that the called object in *$this->seolink* has no properties with the names *mind_the_id* and *simple_replace*.

Your *$this->seolink* links to an (empty) standard class instead of a class with the requested properties.